# R - addressing a data frame column through column name stored as variable

Tags: r, dataframe

**file.csv**

```
group   metric
1       1.1
0       2.2
0       3.3
1       4.4
```

I'm reading the above `file.csv` as below in to a data frame

```
df <- read.csv("file.csv", header=T)
# store col names for using later
group_name <- as.name(colnames(df)[1])
metric_name <- as.name(colnames(df)[2])
```

I can read a specific column by its name as below.

```
> df$group
[1] 1 0 0 1
Levels: 0 1
```

How do I address a specific col using the variables `group_name` & `metric_name`

Tried the following, but it gives error as below.

```
> df[,group_name]
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
```

Comment: There is no need for `as.name` .  `group_name <- colnames(df)[1]` is enough

Answer (score 0):

(Column) names of a data frame are not `name` objects, but its "names" attributes. You can test that by running:

```
> is.name(names(df)[1])
[1] FALSE
```

To use column names by variable, just store their column names without coercing them:

```
group_name <- names(df)[1]
metric_name <- names(df)[2]
```